# portability, should csv file use CRLF line feeds on windows

Tags: windows, csv, portability, newline

I've developed a command line tool which converts some kind of binary data to csv text.
Now I'm going to port it to Windows and I'am still not sure if I should write "\r\n" line feeds specially for Windows or just '\n' as usual.

I'd like to have exactly the same output on all platforms. But I'am not a Windows guy and don't know any problems that may occur.
Do you think the usual data miner on Windows could live without that '\r'?

For example I've tried out "excel", "cmd" and "more" - didn't noticed any problems without '\r'. Notpad missed, but who cares?

cu,
Rudi

Comment: The **only** windows app I have ever found that doesn't like `\n` instead if `\r\n` is notepad. I really wish M$ would fix this. At the end of the day, it's down to the individual application, so as long as it works in the ones you need it to, that's good enough.

Comment: I wouldn't even worry about Notepad. It's a very basic application for very basic tasks. If I was handed a CSV file I would be using Excel, not Notepad.

Comment: FWIW: **The [RFC-4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) ("the CSV memo") specifically calls out CRLF (as the two-character %x0D%x0A pair) as the EOL marker** (and 'requiring' quotes if it appears as data) .. of course, consumers "should be liberal [in what they accept]" and producers should be conservative - eg. strictly emit CRLF as EOL and maybe quote any field with CR *or* LF ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I decided to never output windows line feeds anymore even on stderr and stdout.
BTW I've noticed that writing in O_BINARY mode is about two times faster than default O_TEXT.

This is what I'am doing now:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <io.h>
#endif

...

#ifdef _WIN32
    /* never write CRLF line feeds */
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr),_O_BINARY);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout),_O_BINARY);
#endif
```